# Access Excel parameter passing

Tags: excel, ms-access, parameters, vba

I have a table in access which has to be accessed in excel. I could easily set up a macro where it dumps the whole table and filters based on a particular cell within vba but since I have 20,000 records it slows up the sheet.

Is there a faster way of passing parameter?

The method I tried was one of the answers posted previously

```
•in Excel go to the data ribbon and click the From other sources icon
•click From Microsoft Query
•select MS Access Database* 
•browse for and select your database. 
•in the wizard select the columns you need to import
•on the next page select the column you want to filter on
•select the type of filter you need, i.e. Equals
•instead of selecting a value in the next box enter [Parameter please Bob]
•enter you sort on the next page
•select Return data to Microsoft Excel and finish
```

But I am somehow not able to pass an excel cell as the parameter. I am ultimately trying to get this running in vba but trying to figure out how this works out manually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Aprough, followed through your procedure but could not selects the Parameters field

Comment: You could record a macro of yourself doing the steps manually, then go to the code and replace the parameter string with a cell reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have everything set up, right-click anywhere in your returned data and choose Parameters.  Select your parameter on the left, and choose "Get the value from the following cell:" and then choose the cell with your parameter.  Every time your data refreshes, it will use that cell as the parameter value.  This is how you do it "manually"